# Sequelize Query for counting rows of more than one column

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I have this code

```
     await   expense.model.findAll({
  attributes: { 
    include: [[instance.sequelize.fn("COUNT", instance.sequelize.col('expense_category')), "expenseCount"]] ,  
  },
  where:[{uuid: user.uuid, expense_category: "Home"}]
  }).then(data => {
  res.send(data)
})
```

which is equivalent to

```
select COUNT(expense_category) as expenseCountfrom customers where expense_category= "Home" AND uuid = user.uuid
```

Problem is, since I am going to use the count for `Chart.js`, I would need to query again as I have 3 other `expense_category` which are namely: `Miscellaneous`, `Food and Beverage`, `Transportation`. Is there a way wherein I can make my code above more efficient wherein I wouldn't have to individually query per `expense_category`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming that you have used enums for category.You could use the group inside the findall and remove the other condition for expense category in the where clause like:

```
    await   expense.model.findAll({
  where:{uuid: user.uuid},
  group:['expense_category'],
  attributes: { 
    'expense_category'
    [instance.sequelize.fn("COUNT", instance.sequelize.col('expense_category')), "expenseCount"]  
  }
  }).then(data => {
  res.send(data)
})
```

You will get response like

```
[
 {
   'expense_catogory':"Home",
   'expenseCount': 10
 },
{
   'expense_catogory':"Miscellaneous",
   'expenseCount': 2
 },
{
   'expense_catogory':"Food and Beverage",
   'expenseCount': 7
 },
{
   'expense_catogory':"Transportation",
   'expenseCount': 3
 }
]
```

Comment: If @Niic this answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: This solution worked. I just needed to use group by which I initially lacked. Thanks!